# how to minus sold stock from total stock?

Tags: mysql

Hii i am working on hospital project. My Issue is: i have two table (1). stock and (2). details.

stock table contains total stock of medicines.

details table contains totalstockquantity - soldstock quantity.

for this code i tried :

```
$result=mysql_query(
"SELECT ((stock.quantity)-details.quantity) AS sub,
 stock.id AS id,
 stock.name AS name,
 stock.type AS type,
 stock.batch_no AS batch,
 stock.quantity AS quantity,
 stock.exp AS exp
 FROM stock
 INNER JOIN details on stock.name=details.medicine ");
?>
```

but it gives multiple result of same id.

Comment: You probably have multiple records per medicine in the details table (every use should generate a transaction record).

Comment: yes.. any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT stock.quantity - (select sum(details.quantity) from details where stock.name=details.medicine) AS sub,
 stock.id AS id,
 stock.name AS name,
 stock.type AS type,
 stock.batch_no AS batch,
 stock.quantity AS quantity,
 stock.exp AS exp
 FROM stock
```

Comment: Yeah, this may work on a short term, or in a learning assignment, but this is not sustainable on the long term in a real life situation. In real life, the quantity in the stock table is updated on a regular basis (sometimes even after each transaction). You truly do not want to run such sums on the entire transactions table.

Comment: @Shadow agreed there are many questions that arise from this question and I certainly would not implement this solution without understanding stock movements and where in time stock.quantity is captured (presumably there's an incoming stock process also). Having said that I have to assume the OP has a clearer view of his/her system.